# Элемент который по условию нужно найти

Tags: python

Есть массив `b = {-100, 0, 150, 230}`
Есть элемент `a = 50`
Логика такая значение а должно быть между двумя элементами в массиве и в результате выдать элемент с большЕй индексацией в массиве. Например если значение а ровно 50 то результат 100, если а равен -98 то результат равен 0, если а равен 200 то результат равен 230

```
 b = {-100, 0, 150, 230}
    a = 50
    res = []
    for z in a:
         for (i), (j) in zip(b[:-1], b[1:]):
              if i <= z < j:
              res.append(j)
        
    
    OUT = res
```

Comment: так 50 ближе к 0, чем к 150?

Comment: ок переименовал оглавие вопроса. Помогите с решением

Comment: Логика нетривиальная. Может, поясните другими словами?

Comment: Логику переписал

Comment: а если -150 или 270?

Comment: такой -150 то 230, если 270 , которого нет в массиве то null

Comment: -150 - это ниже левого края, тогда что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте бинарный поиск, тем более что список уже сортирован, и реализация в Python встроенная есть

```
import bisect

b = [-100, 0, 150, 230]
idx = bisect.bisect_left(b, 42)
print(idx, b[idx])   

>>> 2  150
```

P.S. Если число элементов всегда мало, то проще по списку в цикле пройти, пока следующий элемент не станет меньше заданного  - линейный поиск.

Comment: Благодарю очень выручили

Comment: Только не надо переменную называть `id` - это встроенная функция ))  Назовите лучше `idx`, ну или `i`